# How to give json usl in angularJS to display the data on table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hi I have tried with below code but getting an error "GET http://localhost:17627/DataBase.json 404 (Not Found)". please guide me how to give file path in the form of URL. please help me as soon as possible.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in detail">
        <td>{{ x.EmpID }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.EmpName }}</td>
        <td>{{x.EmailId}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:17627/DataBase.json")
        .then(function (response) { $scope.detail = response.data.records; });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide more details? What is this Database.json? Is it a file that is in the root folder of your web project?

Comment: it is a .json file in which I stored data form textbox and in the form of JSON and this file saved on same place where other files resides. file location : c:/users/<UserName>/documents/visual studio 2013/websites/devicetracking/database.json

Comment: database.json != DataBase.json

Comment: Are you sure that your server is configured in order to serve static contents? you can ping the file directly? Try to open this url in a browser tab... 

check if the directory is public, if the case sensitive is respected, and something else...

Comment: yeah I have already changed but still getting the same issue

Comment: I have tried to open the same directory but the it is not opening

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your app.js and database.json are located in the same directory ( c:/users//documents/visual studio 2013/websites/devicetracking)

Also if you are using IIS, make sure to add json as a MIME Type in IIS website you have created for this angular app. It can be done as below:

- Open IIS Manager
- Display properties for the IIS Server
- Click MIME Types and then add the JSON extension: File name extension: .json
  MIME type: application/json

The below code should work

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("database.json")
        .then(function (response) { $scope.detail = response.data.records; });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi sagar,
I have update the path (http://localhost:17627/database.json) with (file:///C:/users/user/documents/visual%20studio%202013/websites/devicetracking/database.json) this and now I am able to open in browser with this path but now I'm getting a different issue that is  Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: i dont think you should add file:/// in $http.get, try using my code above and look at adding MIME type if you are using IIS

Comment: @Sugar I have tried by your code as well and used with file:/// but not working because as I said in error it it saying  Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.” error when loading a local file. so give ne alternative.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? IIS? what is your setup environment?

Comment: I am using visual studio

Comment: Better create a new website in IIS and deploy, thats how it should in real world.

Comment: Hi Sagar, I have created same program in ASP.net and deployed on IIS and first time it works but with in a second data of JSON file again disappeared and giving same issue please help me in this problem. if you want I can show you whole code